# How do I install the drivers for my Samsung printer?

Tags: drivers, printing, software-installation

I have a Samsung `CLP-325w` printer. I downloaded the `.tar.gz` file from their website, but I can't seem to figure out how to install it.

[Here's the link to the driver's tarball](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/CLP-325W/XAA)

I've been following [this guide](http://maketecheasier.com/install-software-from-a-tarball-in-linux/2009/06/25) to install it, but I get stuck at the `./configure` command. It says `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

What am I doing wrong? If I'm in the wrong folder, which folder is the correct one?

I should note that I was able to install the drivers via Ubuntu's generic drivers, but I'd really like to know how to do this for future and also to make sure I have the latest drivers.

Comment: Have you uncompressed the file?

Comment: Yes, it decompresses into a folder called "cdroot". That folder contains another folder called "Linux" which contains the folders "addressbook" "emailbook" "phonebook" and "psu"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Installing the driver

1. Make sure that the machine is connected to your computer and powered on.
2. From [the Samsung website](http://www.samsung.com), download the Unified Linux Driver package to your computer.
3. Right-click the Unified Linux Driver package and **extract the package**.
4. Open one **Terminal** and enter the following commands:

   `cd PSU_1.10.tar.gz`  *(the uncompressed folder)*

   `cd cdroot && cd Linux && cd psu`

   `sudo ./install.sh`
5. Then it'll ask your password, **enter it**.

   Now you should see the following image:

[image: installation_windows]

5. Click on **Next** to start the installation.
6. When the installation is complete, click **Finish**.

---

Source: [Samsung Driver Manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201112/20111222102855370/EN/en/english/start_here.htm)

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. So, I didn't need to perform the ./configure - make - make install commands?

Comment: No, because it is already compiled. There is other software that you can or must compile(config. make, etc.).

Comment: what "SANE API" is this that must be installed?  I installed everything I could see with SANE.

Comment: @Thufir I don't understand your question. What do you mean with *SANE*?

Comment: @Lucio not to hijack the question, but I have a problem installing this driver:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/294965/samsung-driver-doesnt-detect-sane-correctly    when I execute the install script, it warns that SANE isn't installed.  I'm curious that there's no mention of SANE in the question or answer here.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanner_Access_Now_Easy

Answer (score 6):

I used a similar method to install a Samsung M2020W (Express).

- Download the driver. ([driver for Samsung M2020W](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SL-M2020W/XAA))
- Move it to the desktop.
- Extract the folder to the desktop.
- Open a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- `cd Desktop`
- `cd` to the folder (in my case, the folder was called `uld`).
- Run command `sudo ./install.sh`.

Agree with all the "y" prompts, and job done. There was no GUI to run.

Added the printer in the usual way.

Answer (score 6):

I used the [**The Samsung Unified Linux Driver Repository**](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/index.html).

You install it as follows:

```shell
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra" >> /etc/apt/sources.list';  
sudo wget -O - http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/suldr.gpg | sudo apt-key add - ;  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install suld-driver-4.01.17;
```

Comment: returns an error for 2nd command: 404 Not Found

Comment: @Woeitg Right, they've changed the authentication as stated in the news at http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr , the new procedure seems to be explained at http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/forum/index.php?topic=290.0

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/170895/327339) by Lucio didn't work for me. I ended up having to use The [Samsung Unified Linux Driver Repository](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/), like [Huge did in his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/731651/327339), but the instructions I came up with for myself are slightly different:

Essentially following the steps here - http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/

1. Back up `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `sources.list.bak`

   - `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak`
2. To `/etc/apt/sources.list` (root/sudo access required to edit), add the line: 
   `deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra`

   - ex: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, then type in the line and save and exit.
3. Refresh your repository settings: `sudo apt-get update`
4. Install the latest repository key: `sudo apt-get install suldr-keyring`
5. Now install the proper driver!

   1. See here for repository information - http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/repository.html
   2. See here for a list of supported printers - http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/supported.html
6. Find your required driver for your printer in the list of supported printers. Ex: for ML-331x the table recommends 3.00.90.
7. Install this driver as follows: suld-driver-*; for example: `sudo apt-get install suld-driver-3.00.90`
8. Now install the network printer via the “Printers” GUI in Xubuntu.

   - Example screenshots in Ubuntu shown here: https://askubuntu.com/a/513841/327339

     1. Start menu → “Printers” → Add → Printer → click “Network Printer”. Find the “Samsung ML-331x (SEC[mac_address_here], [IP_address_here])” and verify the MAC address and IP address in the name are the correct ones corresponding to the printer you want to install.
     2. Click “Forward” and it should automatically find the driver you just installed above and let you add the printer.
9. Done!

Comment: Part 4 did not work for me; I had to download http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/pool/debian/extra/su/suldr-keyring_2_all.deb and install it by `sudo dpkg -i suldr-keyring_2_all.deb` and only thereafter run `sudo apt update`. [reference](https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/index.html)

Comment: Even if I installed like this, "Printers" GUI did not choose the driver by default. This is in Xubuntu 18.04. But there was IPP protocol available for the network printer unlike without installing the driver. I had to select the correct driver in printer properties afterwards; changed the "Make and Model" field. The default and "recommended" one is "Samsung CLP-310, 2.0.0" whereas the installed one is "Samsung CLP-310 Series" in my case.