# Samsung driver doesn't detect SANE correctly

Tags: drivers, apt, printing, samsung, sane

From 13.04 (server) I'm trying to install the Samsung Unified Printer Driver as specified by https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersSamsung which has a dead link.  In any event, the driver is on the Samsung webpage.

See:

https://askubuntu.com/a/170895/45156

However, I keep getting an error that [SANE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanner_Access_Now_Easy) is missing when I execute the `install.sh` script for the Samsung driver.

However, I seem to have SANE:

```
thufir@dur:~/Downloads/cdroot/Linux$ 
thufir@dur:~/Downloads/cdroot/Linux$ ll
total 136
drwxrwxrwx 5 thufir thufir  4096 May 13 11:54 ./
drwxrwxrwx 3 thufir thufir  4096 May 13 11:54 ../
-r-xr-xr-x 1 thufir thufir  3825 Sep 26  2008 check_installation.sh*
drwxrwxrwx 8 thufir thufir  4096 May 13 11:54 i386/
-r-xr-xr-x 1 thufir thufir  3451 Sep 26  2008 Installer.htm*
-r-xr-xr-x 1 thufir thufir 52321 Sep 26  2008 install.sh*
drwxrwxrwx 5 thufir thufir  4096 May 13 11:54 noarch/
-r-xr-xr-x 1 thufir thufir   204 Sep 17  2007 OEM.ini*
-r-xr-xr-x 1 thufir thufir 52321 Sep 26  2008 uninstall.sh*
drwxrwxrwx 8 thufir thufir  4096 May 13 11:54 x86_64/
thufir@dur:~/Downloads/cdroot/Linux$ 
thufir@dur:~/Downloads/cdroot/Linux$ sudo apt-get install libsane-extras-common  libsane-extras  libsane   libsane-common  sane xsane
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libsane is already the newest version.
libsane-common is already the newest version.
libsane-extras is already the newest version.
libsane-extras-common is already the newest version.
sane is already the newest version.
xsane is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
thufir@dur:~/Downloads/cdroot/Linux$
```

There's no way to get this working through apt?  For 12.04, I don't recall doing this.  It just worked.  However, I'm now running a "server" version (smaller download for a clean install) so I'm thinking that it's missing packages, and that there's a meta package to pull all this in.  I don't recall downloading from Samsung before.

In fact, this printer, and that it was "auto-magically" detected by Ubuntu, back in 11.x, was a factor in choosing Ubuntu.

here's a screenshot from another attempt:

[image: why doesn't it detect SANE??]

Comment: Could you add the output of a screenshoot of your error message?

Comment: @Lucio I added a screenshot, it's just reporting that it can't find SANE.

Comment: What happens if you choice *Install Anyway*?

Comment: ok, well, that works.  I just didn't want to screw something up which couldn't then be un-done.  It sounded like it would mess up apt, possibly.  I know that can happen with Microsoft Windows and drivers.

Comment: Does that mean your issue has been resolved?

Comment: yes, err, but you need to put answer there (if you want points, or I'll answer it if you like).

Comment: Same problem here, clicking on Install Anyway doesn't solve the problem: SimpleScan doesn't detect the scanner...

Comment: What model?  Check the list.