# Dell Unified Linux Driver installer

Tags: 13.04, printing, dell

I'm trying to set up a dell B1160w printer and am having trouble.

I'm using the A00 Unified Linux driver which I can get running but then is says SANE - scanner api is needed.  I have SANE 1.0.23 installed.

When I do "instal anyway" if seems like the printer is installed but it does nothing when I try to print anything (meaning it goes to the print queue, looks like it's about the print the just goes to idle and nothing happens)

Anyone had this problem or have any ides on how to fix it?

Comment: Ever found a solution ? got exactly the same issue with Ubuntu 14.04 and the same printer

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem as described by nhadfield on 8/21/13.   First I looked into
the answer about Ghostscript, but it was already installed.

I had followed the instructions at [How do I install the drivers for my Samsung printer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170880/how-do-i-install-the-tar-gz-for-my-printer-drivers), which
led me to install
B1160_B1160w_UnifiedLinuxDriver_1.01.tar.gz

However, today I discovered also B1160w_Linux_v1.04_Driver.tar.gz
at
http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/driverdetails?driverid=M4HVD

I downloaded this 1.04 version and then installed it as follows using the
Terminal.   It seems to be working.

```
cd
cd Downloads
gunzip B1160w_Linux_v1.04_Driver.tar.gz 
tar -xvf B1160w_Linux_v1.04_Driver.tar 
cd cdroot
cd Linux/
sudo ./install.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Try **http://www.ghostscript.com/**. Install and configure then try and run the installer again.

Comment: Isn't it better adding more details ?. So the reader can get a basic idea before visit website