# HP Laserjet P1102w printer doesn't print over wifi

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and have hplip drivers and the plugin installed. I have configured the printer to my wifi network succesfully and this shows up when go to Settings -> Printers. In the image, both are the same printer.
[Window 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH9oQ.png)

When I send the 'Laserjet' print jobs, it doesn't print. This is its print queue with three print jobs:

[Window 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8VBT.png)

How do I make it print?

It prints fine over USB.

Comment: See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/513713/how-to-configure-a-network-printer-in-ubuntu-14-04/513841#513841

Comment: Can you able to print via lan?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the IPP print driver. I've set my P1102W at a fixed IP address using reserved IP/DHCP in my router, and then used the socket print driver, like so:

[image]