# ubuntu 16.04 shows red exclamation mark on printer

Tags: 16.04, printing

I am not able to print anything from ubuntu 16.04 machine. It is showing red exclamation mark as shown in the image. Machine is connected with printer via LAN.

When I click on add (+) button then my printer does not show in network printer option. See image.

Please suggest some workaround.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like your printer driver is trying to connect to the printer via localhost. How is this printer connected? Is it via USB/WiFi/LAN cable? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1006668/edit) your question and provide the new information up there.

Comment: If this is a network printer, connected either by WiFi or Ethernet, make sure the computer and the printer are both on the same network. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/513713/how-to-configure-a-network-printer-in-ubuntu-14-04/513841#513841 for how to setup a network printer.