# help seting up printer networking

Tags: 18.04

I have two computers with ubuntu 18.04 and trying to let them both use one printer. They are wired through a modem that they both share. I am not a computer guru so any help would appreciated.

Comment: please update the question with the models of what printer and what modem they are connected with

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1123522/edit) **your question above**. Add more information about the printer: 1. The make and model, 2. How is the printer connected: (a) USB to computer A or B, (b) Ethernet cable to the router or modem, (c) WiFi to home network, (d) Other (Specify).

Comment: For network printers see: [How to configure a network printer in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513713/how-to-configure-a-network-printer-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

If the printer is USB only, connect it to one computer, add the printer, and share the printer on the network. One the second computer, have it look for a network printer and add it.

[image]

If the printer is wireless or ethernet, connect the printer to your network, then add a network printer on both computers.

If it's an HP printer, you'll want to install the HPLIP software suite, see [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing), or in Synaptic, and the specific HP printer driver software.

Other printer vendors may also have Linux/Ubuntu compatible printer specific software. Check their web sites.
[image]

Comment: Cannon and other makes may also need make and model specific driver/software installation to work properly.