# Printing Black and White in Evince?

Tags: printing, evince

Unfortunately, I see no options in Evince under the section "color". My printer is a 
HP-Deskjet-2540 series. Many thanks in advance!

@user68186: Thanks for the hints. Here is a screenshot from my Ubuntu 18.04 system:

[image]
Note that my laptop is connected to my printer via WiFi and that my printer was automatically recognized by Ubuntu (during installation, I had checked the box "Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats").

Comment: Please edit the question and indicate how your computer is connected to the printer, is it via USB cable, WiFi, or Ethernet cable, or something else? Then add information about how you installed the printer driver? If you did nothing and the printer was recognized, you may have to install some printer diriver/utility. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or for how to install `HPLIP`.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/513713/how-to-configure-a-network-printer-in-ubuntu-14-04/513841#513841 for network printer installation.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: Thanks for the question! No, unfortunately not. I uninstalled HPLIP, but then the printer wouldn't print and I found it annoying because there were so many unnecessary notificiations from it, that I uninstalled HPLIP yesterday night. I followed your first link so far.

Comment: Please update the question with what you tried and what did not work.