# How do I resolve a connection issue I'm having between my laptop and my Brother printer?

Tags: 20.04, printing

Brother HL-L2305w Laser Printer for CUPS

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, 64 bit

GNOME: 3.36.8

Used linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.2-2 to install drivers.

Printer and laptop are connected to the same WiFi SSID network.
Test prints can be made directly from the printer but not from the laptop.

Note: This printer was previously connected to a Windows machine and one test print indicates that the Windows drivers are still installed.

```
$ avahi-discover
Browsing domain 'local' on -1.-1 ...
Browsing for services of type '_http._tcp' in domain 'local' on 3.0 ...
Browsing for services of type '_ipp._tcp' in domain 'local' on 3.0 ...
Browsing for services of type '_printer._tcp' in domain 'local' on 3.0 ...
Browsing for services of type '_pdl-datastream._tcp' in domain 'local' on 3.0 ...
Found service 'Brother HL-L2305 series' of type '_http._tcp' in domain 'local' on 3.0.
Found service 'Brother HL-L2305 series' of type '_ipp._tcp' in domain 'local' on 3.0.
Found service 'Brother HL-L2305 series' of type '_printer._tcp' in domain 'local' on 3.0.
Found service 'Brother HL-L2305 series' of type '_pdl-datastream._tcp' in domain 'local' on 3.0.
```

```
$ avahi-browse -rt _ipp._tcp
+   wlo1 IPv4 Brother HL-L2305 series                       Internet Printer     local
Failed to resolve service 'Brother HL-L2305 series' of type '_ipp._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
```

Recent dmesg: https://pastebin.com/gS2CQq0f

[Here](https://pastebin.com/xfSGhfJY) are the results of running the various commands suggested in [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems) troubleshooting guide.

It seems that the laptop and printer cannot "see" each other so printing from the laptop is not possible. Solutions?

Comment: Find the IP address of the printer from the printer's display and menu. Use the IP address to discover the printer in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 

https://pastebin.com/xfSGhfJY

Those are the results of running the various commands suggested in this troubleshooting guide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems

What's it all mean? :)

Comment: Please update your question with the link to the pastebin. The comments are our channel to reach you, you should always update the question and then start a comment with attention to the user you are responding to with "@user68186" for example, so that I am notified.  It means the IP address of the printer is 10.0.0.110. Try to add the printer following [How to configure a network printer in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513713/how-to-configure-a-network-printer-in-ubuntu-14-04) and update your question with the results. Note the pictures in this answer may not match yours.

Answer (score 0):

@user68186's referral to [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513713/how-to-configure-a-network-printer-in-ubuntu-14-04) led me to the solution. In particular, adding the printer's IP address via the "Find Network Printer" feature did the trick! Thanks so much! :)