# How to get working Samsung SL-M2070W printer on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

I have problems installing the driver for my printer Samsung SL-M2070W. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Any advice? I have downloaded the .tar.gz driver from Samsung website, but I don't know how to use it and if it even works.

---

Thank you for your advice. It was an .sh file. I installed it, but when I try to print a document nothing happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the drivers for my Samsung printer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/170880/how-do-i-install-the-drivers-for-my-samsung-printer)

Comment: This might be a duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/170880/how-do-i-install-the-drivers-for-my-samsung-printer

Answer (score 11):

If you did not understand a word of that, don't worry. I did not either.

Here is an alternative, but you may have to use a Windows computer to update the firmware on your Samsung M2070 FW printer. Once that is done, connect it to your router using WPS, or your preferred method. Once the printer is connected to the wireless network, your Ubuntu based computer will detect the printer.

Now go to System Settings, and then Printers, and hit ADD PRINTER,and the wizard will start.

Click NETWORK PRINTER, and choose 'Samsung M2070 FW'.

On the lower right hand corner, choose APP SOCKET/HP DIRECT. Your port settings will display, but you will probably not want to mess with that.

The Wizard will then search for drivers. 
But wait! The Samsung M2070 FW is not in the driver list. No problem.

Under PRINTERS choose GENERIC, and on the next menu choose GENERIC PCL LASER.

Finish up the wizard and you are in business!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

To unzip the tar file, you can use terminal:

```
cd /path/to/download/directory
tar -xvzf filename.tar.gz
```

Then, you can

```
cd filename
ls -a
```

to see what's inside.

1. If it's an .sh file extension, you can simply run

   sudo sh file.sh
2. If it's a ppd file:

   sudo apt-get install cups
   sudo /etc/init.d/cupsd start
   sudo update-rc.d cupsd add

Then go to http://127.0.0.1:631.
There's an administration tab at the top. Click on it and click add printer after attaching your printer. Follow the wizard and provide the ppd file when requested.

Comment: having you written the last two lines after point 2, I wonder if point 1 produces a ppd file or not.